# Pandoc unable to find images converting LaTeX do MS Doc

Tags: graphics, pandoc

I am experimenting with `pandoc` to convert a LaTeX document to the MS Doc format. The LaTeX document compiles without errors using `pdflatex`. However, when trying to convert into Doc format `pandoc` complains it cannot find the images files. An example:

```
$ pandoc main.tex --filter pandoc-crossref -o main.docx
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'figures/SPGZ00': PandocResourceNotFound "figures/SPGZ00"
```

This is the corresponding LaTeX segment:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figures/SPGZ00}
\end{figure}
```

What could be going wrong?

**Update I**: Making sure there is only one file with the corresponding name in the `figures` folder:

```
$ ls figures/SPGZ00*
figures/SPGZ00.png
$
```

**Update II**: Below a reproduction of this issue with the smallest document I could muster. A minimal non-working example.

```
$ cat minimal.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section*{An image}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figures/SPGZ00}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

$ pdflatex minimal.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./minimal.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./figures/SPGZ00.png>]
(./minimal.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on minimal.pdf (1 page, 230844 bytes).
Transcript written on minimal.log.

$ pandoc minimal.tex --filter pandoc-crossref -o minimal.docx
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 'figures/SPGZ00': PandocResourceNotFound "figures/SPGZ00"

$ pandoc --version
pandoc 2.5
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.5.4, texmath 0.11.2.2, skylighting 0.7.7
Default user data directory: /home/duque004/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2018 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
```

Comment: Just guessing: You have not a file named  "SPGZ00", but  one o more files like "SPGZ00.png", or "SPGZ00.jpg" or "SPGZ00.pdf". LaTeX  guess that you really want to use some of these images in a predetermined preference order, but probably pandoc expect to know that  without ambiguity.

Comment: @Fran there is only one file with that name, I am updating the question.

Comment: What happens when you specify: includegraphics[scale=0.4]{figures/SPGZ00.png} ?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I am not suggesting that the problem is only that you could have more than one image, but that you omit the extension, and this is  fine for  LaTeX, but probably not for pandoc exports. Try what Miloop suggested.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and the version of pandoc you are using.

Comment: With your MWE I have checked that the problem is the omitted extension, as Fran and Miloop suggested.

Comment: @SergioLlorente The `graphicx` package recommends omitting the extension. In any case, this is perfectly valid LaTeX code, therefore I would expect `pandoc` to be able to deal with it.